# custom hook not triggering in component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, styled-components

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/04/dark-mode-react-apps-styled-components/) for creating themes for night/day modes with styled-components.

I created a hook `useDarkMode` and for some reason, while it's detecting changes locally to the `theme` state within the hook, it's not sending these updates to my component (`_app.tsx`) where it needs to be read.

Am I missing something obvious here, why isn't `theme` changing on `_app.tsx`?

**useDarkMode hook**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const useDarkMode = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light');

  const setMode = (mode) => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('theme', mode);
    setTheme(mode);
  };

  const themeToggler = () => {
    theme === 'light' ? setMode('dark') : setMode('light');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('theme:', theme);  <=== triggers and shows theme has been updated
  }, [theme]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const localTheme = window.localStorage.getItem('theme');
    console.log('localTheme', window.localStorage.getItem('theme'));
    localTheme && setTheme(localTheme);
  }, []);

  return [theme, themeToggler];
};
```

**_app.tsx**

```
function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const store = useStore(pageProps.initialReduxState);

  const [theme] = useDarkMode();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('t', theme);  <=== only triggers on component mount, theme is not updating
  }, [theme]);

  const themeMode = theme === 'light' ? LIGHT_THEME : DARK_THEME;

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={themeMode}>
        <RootPage Component={Component} pageProps={pageProps} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

**where it's being invoked**

```
const TopNav = () => {
  const [theme, themeToggler] = useDarkMode();

  return (
    <Content className="full-bleed">
      <NavInner>
        <AuthLinks>
  
            <>
              <button onClick={themeToggler}>Switch Theme</button>
              <Link href="/user/login" passHref>
                <div>
                  <Typography format="body1">Login</Typography>
                </div>
              </Link>
              <Link href="/user/register" passHref>
                <div>
                  <Typography format="body1">Register</Typography>
                </div>
              </Link>
            </>

         ...
        </AuthLinks>
      </NavInner>
    </Content>
  );
};
```

Comment: Where are you calling themeToggler?

Comment: `themeToggler` is never invoked, it is not even destructured from the `useDarkMode` hook.

Comment: @DrewReese ah, yeah. I didn't include the file with my button, it's there now. It is being triggered on click. So there's that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Each react hook is its own instance, they don't share state.

## Suggested Solution

Use a single dark mode theme state in the provider and expose the `themeToggler` in a context so all components can update the same context value.

Theme toggle context

```
const ThemeToggleContext = React.createContext({
  themeToggler: () => {},
});
```

App

```
import { ThemeToggleContext } from 'themeToggleContext';

function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const store = useStore(pageProps.initialReduxState);

  const [theme, themeToggler] = useDarkMode();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('t', theme);  <=== only triggers on component mount, theme is not updating
  }, [theme]);

  const themeMode = theme === 'light' ? LIGHT_THEME : DARK_THEME;

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={themeMode}>
        <ThemeToggleContext.Provider value={themeToggler} > // <-- pass themeToggler to context provider
          <RootPage Component={Component} pageProps={pageProps} />
        </ThemeToggleContext>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Component

```
import { ThemeToggleContext } from 'themeToggleContext';

const TopNav = () => {
  const themeToggler = useContext(ThemeToggleContext); // <-- get the context value

  return (
    <Content className="full-bleed">
      <NavInner>
        <AuthLinks>
  
            <>
              <button onClick={themeToggler}>Switch Theme</button>
              <Link href="/user/login" passHref>
                <div>
                  <Typography format="body1">Login</Typography>
                </div>
              </Link>
              <Link href="/user/register" passHref>
                <div>
                  <Typography format="body1">Register</Typography>
                </div>
              </Link>
            </>

         ...
        </AuthLinks>
      </NavInner>
    </Content>
  );
};
```

Comment: Brilliant, I appreciate you taking the time to write that out for me. It didn't even occur to me that I was creating two separate states for my hooks, no wonder it was triggering the console logs in one area but not another.